# Python os.walk() loop directories for attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file containing directory names on each line (1, 2, 3), how can I iterate through the text file and have the result inserted into os.walk?

So far, I have

```
import os
from os import listdir

dir_file = open("list.txt", "r")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_file):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

I have used a combination of while loops and for loops and if statements to try and perform this, but I've had no luck.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: you've got to iterate the `dir_file` first

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
rdf = []
for fff in dir_file:
   for r, d, f in os.walk(fff):
      rdf.append(r, d, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with:

```
import os
from os import listdir

dir_file = open("list.txt", "r")

for x in dir_file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x.strip()):
        for name in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
        for name in dirs:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Thanks :)